# x86: Why carry flag not set when moving to memory address?

Tags: x86, yasm

I realize this may look like a dup, but I've not found anything quite like my question. Say I have in yasm:

```
segment .data

a  db 0

...

main:

    mov rax, 0xffffffff

    mov [a], rax
```

Why doesn't the carry flag get set when moving into a? It's only a byte! When I've clearly moved into it much larger than a byte. In fact in gdb the entire number gets stored in a. How is that possible given its declaration?

Comment: In general flags are only affected by ALU operations, not by load/store operations.

Comment: Because Intel manual says so.

Answer (score 2):

Because `mov` doesn't set flags.  There isn't any deeper reason than that.

Quoting the Intel instruction set reference manual:

> **Flags Affected**
>
> None.

Comment: The "deeper reason" is probably that loads and stores typically do not involve the ALU.

Comment: @PaulR: One could make the LSU update flags without much trouble. The deeper reason is really that having `mov` not set flags makes it easier to write efficient software, but it's hard to get too far down that path without bringing in lots of example code.

Comment: It would take a lot of extra logic to do that in modern superscalar CPUs - the load/store unit(s) and the ALU(s) are largely independent and execute out-of-order a lot of the time. Doing this would also introduce some nasty dependencies which would result in more pipeline stalls.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes sense! but one other question, how does it store the entire  0xffffffff when it's only been declared as byte? Shouldn't it have been truncated? The code


        mov [a], 0xffffffff /

        mov rax, [a]

I'd expect to see in rax 0xff, which is the largest number a can store, isn't it?

Comment: @user2022444: It only *stores* the low byte of `rax` to `[a]`, but it does not modify the value in `rax` at all.

Answer (score 0):

The carry bit gets set with mathematical operations only. You might be thinking of the overflow bit, but this also does nothing in this case.

As Stephen rightly says:

`mov` doesn't set flags